# Javascript: the logic about elem.closest()

Tags: javascript, css, frontend

when I put multiple tagNames and classNames in the brackets of elem.closest(), as follows

```
table.onclick = function(event) {  
      let target = event.target.closest('.none-class,none-elem,td,.none-class2,none-elem2'); 
      console.log(target);
}
```

even if the classes and tags do not exist except the 'td' element. it always return the 'td' element.
 As I understand  the "CSS selector rule", if the elements are separated by comma, it means 'and', so it "Selects all elements ". While here the comma means 'or'. Could someone tell me the logic of how the 'elem.closest()' works?

Comment: It's basically the *return first match* you'd have in querySelector vs querySelectorAll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.closest()` will search through ancestors and return the first one which corresponds to selector.

**Comma means OR**. So your selector is as follows:

Give me first ancestor which:

- Has "none-class" class **OR**
- Is a custom HTML tag `<none-elem>` **OR**
- Is a HTML tag `<td>` **OR**
- Has "none-class2" class **OR**
- Is a custom HTML tag `<none-elem2>`

So your closest ancestor  corresponds to the third rule in your selector.

If you want to write a selector with **AND**, you will have to write something like `td.none-class2` or `none-elem.none-class`. Notice no space before dot

Answer (score 0):

There is no special meaning of css selectors in the `closest()` - function. The comma in a css-selector actually always means OR in the logical sense. So the rule will match any of these:

```
.none-class
none-elem
td
.none-class2
...
```

If you want it to match eg. only if the td has a .none-class, use:

```
td.none-class
```

as the selector. Read up more on css selectors.